# Spark: PySpark + Cassandra query performance

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I have setup Spark 2.0 and Cassandra 3.0 on a local machine (8 cores, 16gb ram) for testing purposes and edited `spark-defaults.conf` as follows:

```
spark.python.worker.memory 1g
spark.executor.cores 4
spark.executor.instances 4
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 4
```

Next I imported 1.5 million rows in Cassandra:

```
test(
    tid int,
    cid int,
    pid int,
    ev list<double>,
    primary key (tid)
)
```

`test.ev` is a list containing numeric values i.e. `[2240,2081,159,304,1189,1125,1779,693,2187,1738,546,496,382,1761,680]`

Now in the code, to test the whole thing I just created a `SparkSession`, connected to Cassandra and make a simple select count:

```
cassandra = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
df = cassandra.load(keyspace="testks",table="test")
df.select().count()
```

At this point, Spark outputs the `count` and takes about 28 seconds to finish the `Job`, distributed in 13 `Tasks` (in `Spark UI`, the total Input for the Tasks is 331.6MB)

**Questions:**

- Is that the expected performance? If not, what am I missing?
- Theory says the number of partitions of a DataFrame determines the number of tasks Spark will distribute the job in. If I am setting the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to 4, why is creating 13 Tasks? (Also made sure the number of partitions calling `rdd.getNumPartitions()` on my DataFrame)

***Update***

A common operation I would like to test over this data:

- Query a large data set, say, from 100,000 ~ N rows grouped by `pid`
- Select `ev`, a `list<double>`
- Perform an average on each member, assuming by now each list has the same length i.e `df.groupBy('pid').agg(avg(df['ev'][1]))`

<strike>As *@zero323* suggested, I deployed a external machine (2Gb RAM, 4 cores, SSD) with Cassandra just for this test, and loaded the same data set. The result of the `df.select().count()` was an expected greater latency and overall poorer performance in comparison with my previous test (took about 70 seconds to finish the `Job`).</strike>

**Edit:** I misunderstood his suggestion. *@zero323* meant to let Cassandra perform the count instead of using Spark SQL, as explained in [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#counting-rows)

Also I wanted to point out that I am aware of the inherent anti-pattern of setting a `list<double>` instead a wide row for this type of data, but my concerns at this moment are more the time spent on retrieval of a large dataset rather than the actual average computation time.

Comment: If you want to perform count then querying external source is way more efficient. In general a lot depends on what you do. Regarding partitions `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is not used here. Initial number of partitions is set by data source and count always uses 1 task for final aggregation.

Comment: thank you again @zero323. Please check my update. Also, if I understand correctly, you are saying the number of partitions are set by Cassandra?

Comment: OK< I think I wasn't clear enough :/ My point was to perform query directly against Cassandra without using Spark SQL if you perform simple actions like count all rows. Not deploying separate server.

Comment: Regarding the number of partitions take a look at `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb` parameter and how it relates to the total number of partitions. Also for simple count  take a look at `cassandraCount` on Cassandra backed RDDs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that the expected performance? If not, what am I missing?

It looks slowish but it is not exactly unexpected. In general `count` is expressed as

```
SELECT 1 FROM table
```

followed by Spark side summation. So while it is optimized it still rather inefficient because you have fetch N long integers from the external source just to sum these locally.

As explained by [the docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#counting-rows) Cassandra backed RDD (not `Datasets`) provide optimized `cassandraCount` method which performs server side counting.

> Theory says the number of partitions of a DataFrame determines the number of tasks Spark will distribute the job in. If I am setting the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to  (...), why is creating (...) Tasks?

Because `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is not used here. This property is used to determine number of partitions for shuffles (when data is aggregated by some set of keys) not for `Dataset` creation or global aggregations like `count(*)` (which always use 1 partition for final aggregation).

If you interested in controlling number of initial partitions you should take a look at [`spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/75719dfe0e175b3e0bb1c06127ad4e6930c73ece/doc/reference.md#read-tuning-parameters) which defines:

> Approx amount of data to be fetched into a Spark partition. Minimum number of resulting Spark partitions is 1 + 2 * SparkContext.defaultParallelism

As you can see another factor here is `spark.default.parallelism` but it is not exactly a subtle configuration so depending on it in general is not an optimal choice.

Comment: That was really, really illustrative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see that it is very old question but maybe someone needs it now.
When running Spark on local machine it is very important to set into SparkConf master "local[*]" that according to documentation allows to run Spark with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.

It helped me to increase performance of count() operation by 100% on local machine comparing to master "local".