# Slow count of >1 billion rows from Cassandra via Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a problem with a simple rows counting from cassandra's table. I'm using `spark-cassandra-connector` to fetch data from cassandra:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0"
```

With this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectionFactory

object Init {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "host")
//      .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "65000")
      .setAppName("spark2Cassandra")
      .setMaster("local[*]")

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val table = sparkContext.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table")
    println(table.count())
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get about 2k partitions and 40 parallel tasks and it takes about 1 hour.
In this case: [1 billion for 5-6 mins](https://codexample.org/questions/920705/apache-spark-taking-5-to-6-minutes-for-simple-count-of-1-billon-rows-from-cassandra.c) it takes only 5-6 mins. But why?

What should I do to decrease time?

---

Unfortunately, this [Spark: PySpark + Cassandra query performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576448/spark-pyspark-cassandra-query-performance) doesn't give me an answer on my question. I also tried to use cassandraCount() but it takes an about hour to

Comment: @Nick Ryan There are lot of factors that contribute to speed in distributed environment. The original OP in codeexample.org did not post an cluster specs, they could be completely different from yours. Besides running operation like `count()` is an anti-pattern in C* as it puts lot of stress on the C* cluster and devs are reluctant to use it in prod evn's.

Comment: Thank you! Probably you are right, i didn't consider their cluster specs. Well, i'll try another way then

Comment: @NickRyan Hi. Have you found a better way? I encountered the similar issue. Worse, it took 20 hours or more. In you case, how did you configure your cassandra and spark?